# Storing Chars Into Strings in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variables, chars

So right now I have this code that generates random letters in set increments determined by user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int sLength = 0;
static const char alphanum[] =
"0123456789"
"!@#$%^&*"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;

char genRandom()
{
    return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}

int main()
{
    cout << "What is the length of the string you wish to match?" << endl;
    cin >> sLength;
    while(true)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sLength; x++)
        {
            cout << genRandom();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

I'm looking for a way to store the first (user defined amount) of chars into a string that I can use to compare against another string. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
string s(sLength, ' ');
```

before `while (true)`, change

```
cout << genRandom();
```

to

```
s[x] = genRandom();
```

in your loop, and remove the `cout << endl;` statement.  That will replace all of the printing by putting the characters into `s`.

Comment: This works except for the string s(sLength); It pops out an error. It is invalid conversion from int to const char.

Comment: @Cistoran: I was assuming it worked like `vector` (which can be constructed that way).  I'll fix it.

Comment: Better to do s.reserve(sLength) - then you don't have to write each position twice.

Comment: @kotlinski: I am writing the elements using `[]` rather than `push_back`, so I would need `resize` rather than `reserve`; I think `resize` would write to all of the elements as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about this?

```
    std::string s;
    for (int x = 0; x < sLength; x++)
    {
        s.push_back(genRandom());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
// ...

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));  // forget me not
    while(true) {
        cout << "What is the length of the string you wish to match?" << endl;
        cin >> sLength;
        string r(sLength, ' ');
        generate(r.begin(), r.end(), genRandom);
        cout << r << endl;
    }

}
```